# C# Inconsistent Accessibility winform singleton error

Tags: c#, winforms, singleton

I have this code, it's meant to be a singleton form that pops up and stays up and then is appended to (basically I have muti-threads that can give queries to the user, and I don't want a stack of them I want one to pop up then "keep filling") I am just setting up a basic test case class to check the logic but I got this error I don't understand

error:

```
 Error  2   Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ActionType>' is less accessible than field 'frmVerdict.thingsToDo'
```

code:

```
public partial class frmVerdict : Form
{
    public List<ActionType> thingsToDo = new List<ActionType>();
    private int elementCounter = 0;
    private static frmVerdict _instance;

    public frmVerdict()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public static frmVerdict GetInstance()
    {
        if (_instance == null) _instance = new frmVerdict();
        return _instance;
    }
    public void addAction(ActionType action)
    {
        elementCounter++;
        TextBox txtbx = new TextBox(); //TextBox txtbx = (TextBox)Controls["txtbx0001"];
        txtbx.Text = action.name;
        txtbx.Name = "txtbx" + elementCounter.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0');
        txtbx.Location = new Point(10, 30 * elementCounter);
        txtbx.Height = 20;
        txtbx.Width = 50;
        pnlVerdict.Controls.Add(txtbx); //these textboxes will be replaced by buttons
        thingsToDo.Add(action);            
    }
}
```

here is how I call it (this isn't the problem but I want people to know why I am doing the singleton)

```
frmVerdict form = frmVerdict.GetInstance();
if (!form.Visible)
{
    form.Show();
}
else
{
    form.BringToFront();
}
form.addAction(action);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ActionType` type is either declared as `internal` or has no accessibility modifier, in which case it's `internal` by default.

The solution is to explicitly make it `public` or to make any members of public types which expose `ActionType` internal.

**Further Reading**

- [Access Modifiers (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the class ActionType public because the class frmVerdict has at least one public method that has ActionType as a parameter

Comment: things is `ActionType` is an abstract class, it's always a typeof one of 8 child classes I don't care which one of the 8 it is I don't want to instance ActionType or let anyone :-(

Comment: @user26676 `abstract` has to do with how with inheritance / instantiation, it doesn't affect the accessibility of the type. If you want to limit it so that only your types can inherit it, make the type `public`, but the constructor `internal`.

Comment: @p.s.w.g I made it `public abstract class ActionType` still gives the errors

Comment: @user26676 What errors? Presumably it's not exactly the same error.

Comment: @p.s.w.g you're right, new errors: which are rippling up the application like bomb waves of misery, but you're right, and while it made me sad I cleaned them all up but thwacking `public` about .. by the way is this the right way to go about it ? the whole idea I am going for or is this barking up the wrong tree

Comment: @user26676 Well, it's hard to know without seeing the full context, but having a `public` class with an `internal` constructor is a very common technique provide a limited public API which is extended internally. It's used quite a bit within the .NET framework, too.